# Reverse Engineering Filter Laplacian Equation from Bode Plot

Tags: filter, laplace-transform

I am dealing with a particular filter that I was told has the response curve shown below in red. [image]

I am trying to figure out how quickly this filter could settle to n-bits from a step function input. I could do this if I had the Laplacian representation of the filter and plotted a step input in Matlab. I only have the plot below and response is different than anything I am used to as the roll-off of the filter appears to get "faster" very quickly and not stay at some multiple of -20dB/decade (for x number of poles). Any advice for how to figure out the filter settling time or arrive at a Laplacian representation of the filter response?

Comment: can you make the x axis logscale (looks linear). And phase might help.

Answer (score 2):

The -3dB ratios per half octave may give you some clues why this and where it is being filtered.

Such as GBW limits or ADC limits.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A fairly easy method is to chose a prototype equation for the filter and use a Least Squared Error approach to chose coefficients. I.e. if you want to model the filter as first order lowpass, you have something like:

\$\frac{A}{1 + Bs}\$

where A and B are your "knobs" you can tune. Compare response of your desired filter and your trial filters for many A and B values and take the one with the least error.

Can even approximate more, in your case you have no DC gain, so if you model as a first order filter you only sweep one variable (related to bandwidth).